# Load Relations.csv file to Neo4j Database

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a relations csv file. I have to load this relations to neo4j but i can't.I have already created my News node and this nodes have unique id.

The csv file has `iStart, iRel, iEnd` columns. Thanks

Sample `.csv` file looks like this:

```
iStart    iRel    iEnd
------------------------
114471    IS      2225
```

and this is my code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///try.csv" as input 
MATCH (from:News {id: input.iStart}), (to:News {id: input.iEnd}) 
CREATE (from)-[:RELATION { type: input.iRel }]->(to);
```

Comment: 1. Does your CSV file actually have a lot of blank lines and a dashed line? If so, get rid of those lines.
2. Make sure you have read [the documentation for LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/).
3. Whenever you ask a question, you *have to* show your code.

Comment: sorry now i update

Comment: Can you answer my question #1? And did you do #2, so that you know how to configure the server to enable data imports? Also, what does "i can't" mean? What exactly happens, and do you get any errors?

Comment: No there is no blank. #1 'no changes, no records' this the error. #2 when i write content instead of id it's working by the way

Comment: Does the file have a line of dashes? Can you edit your question to show the actual file contents?

Comment: When the nodes were imported, did you use `toInteger()` so that the ids were numeric? If so, you'll need to use `toInteger()` here as well so that you're matching to values of the same type (so it's not looking for strings when the nodes in graph are using integers).

Comment: Can you share your query to import these nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///try.csv' as input 
CREATE (fromnews:FromNews{id: input.iStart}),(tonews:ToNews{id: input.iEnd})
WITH fromnews,tonews 
CREATE (fromnews)-[:RELATION{type: input.iRel}]->(tonews );
```